# in a ASP.net MVC 2 how Separate the Main DLL?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

We are developing a web application with Entity Framework, MVC2, VS2010. VS2010 generates one large DLL when compiled. Is there an option or way for VS2010 to separate the project in two by generating two DLL ?

Comment: Any particular reason to what two DLL's from the one generated?  Otherwise Justins suggestion sounds the most appropiate

Comment: For security reason. We want to outsource some programming work and would prefer to keep part of the code compiled, i.e. confidential.

Comment: @Jean-Francois You know that compiled code can be de-compiled right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a separate class library project that you can then reference. That is the only way that I know of to create more than one DLL.

[Youtube video of add/remove reference.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZT9fNxq_yeY)

[MSDN article on how to add/remove references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

Comment: Can you provide me a link on how to do that?. I'm really confuse about that.

Comment: File => Add => New Project. Choose Windows Class Library and name it something like MyProject.Models. Then in your "Web" project, Project => Add References. On the Projects tab, select your MyProjects.Models.

Comment: @Jean-Francois Nick's solution is correct, and simple. If you want more verbose tutorials, I have updated the answer